# processQueue() is not working in multiple uploads

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

I use dropzone.js for uploading image. I use this code

```
init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
    myDropzone = this; // closure
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("test");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (strUser == 0) {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.       
        }
    });
}
```

But My processQueue upload only two image.But  if i using auto process then all file uploaded.

I am trying to use this in my processquee function

```
while (i < parallelUploads) {
    if (!queuedFiles.length) {
        return;
    }
    this.processFile(queuedFiles.shift());
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Note you seem to declare a global variable myDropzone. You probably want a local variable instead (you should). Use `var mydropzone = this`.

Comment: Besides, the code you show references some variables that you are not telling us anything about (parallelUploads, queuedFiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set options of your dropzone.js:

`parallelUploads: 30,
 uploadMultiple: true`

in parallelUploads you can set a different value from 1 and higher. 
Good day to you.